# Есть двухмерный массив, нужно посчитать среднее арифметичное всех положительных чисел

Tags: python

Есть двухмерный массив, нужно посчитать среднее арифметичное всех положительных чисел.

```
list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

что должно следовать после того, как я создам этот самый массив?

Comment: Вам нужно считать для каждого подсписка или для всего массива сразу?

Comment: для всего массива сразу

Comment: я вам написал в ответе, что не следует называть свои переменные именами встроенных функций. то есть, это плохая практика назвать список именем `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не называйте свои переменные именами встроенных функций python.

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]


res = [x for y in lst for x in y] # превращаем двумерный список в одномерный
res = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, res)) # отсеиваем положительные числа 
my_mean = sum(res)/len(res) # вычисляем арифметическое среднее
print(my_mean)
```

> 13.235294117647058

без lambda:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, -25]]

def checkpositive(a):
    return a>0

res = [x for y in lst for x in y]
res = list(filter(checkpositive, res))
print (res)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

Comment: спасибо! Что такое lambda?

Comment: lambda - это анонимная функция. этот оператор позволяет писать неименованные функции непосредственно в теле других функций. я обновил ответ, там функция lambda заменена на именованную функцию checkpositive

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3, 4, -5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, -25]]

number_positive_numbers = sum([sum(k+1 for j in i if j>0) for i in myList])

sum_positive_numbers = sum([sum(j for j in i if j>0) for i in myList])

arithmetic_mean_positive_numbers = sum_positive_numbers / number_positive_numbers

print(arithmetic_mean_positive_numbers)
13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

selected = [el for sublist in lst for el in sublist if el > 0]
print(sum(selected)/len(selected))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 13.235294117647058
> ```